# Solve Linear equation with variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algebra.js

I am trying to use JavaScript to solve the linear equation with variables.

So my try is this:

```
            var CE = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CE").value)
            var CF = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CF").value)
            var EF = parseFloat(document.getElementById("EF").value)
            var x1=algebra.parse("CE^2+2*EF*x-EF^2");
            var x2=algebra.parse("CF^2");
            var eq= new Equation(x1,x2);

            var h=eq.solveFor("x");
```

I know I should not put the valuable in "" mark, but I do not know where I should put them.

Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template String in ES-6 to simplify writing these complicated string.

```
var x1=algebra.parse(`${CE}^2+2*${EF}*x-${EF}^2`);
var x2=algebra.parse(`${CF}^2`);
var eq= new Equation(x1,x2);
var h=eq.solveFor("x");
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response, However, it is not working. Still stops at where I have the problem.

Comment: Can you please tell what is the problem because it is working for me

Comment: Hi @ShunichiOno, updated my answer. Can you please check now

Comment: I am sorry, but it did not work on mine. CE, CF, EF are actually user input. And those are set to numbers. The problem for now is algebra.parse is not working.

Comment: Are you getting correct values of variables `CE`, `CF`, `EF`? If you are getting that correct please share what you are getting in `x1` and `x2`

Comment: CE, EF, CF are correct and used in some other function part, but they are in type of number. The input box is set to type = "number". When I try to use parseFloat($(document.getElementById("EF")).text());, it did not work to me.

Comment: `parseFloat(document.getElementById("CE").value)` will also work on `input` fields as you were using it earliar. Please tell me where you are facing the issue? In reading these values or in algebra part? and exactly what error you are facing?

Comment: Right now I am having problem with algebra part.

Comment: exactly what error you are facing? Have you included the algebra script properly?

Comment: I don't get the error message, so I cannot tell what exact error is. I am also not sure about whether I included the algebra script properly or not. I have downloaded it and put "src = ...". That is what I did.